# Allow access to weblink only via native iOS and Android apps

Tags: javascript, android, ios, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have website link at which I have designed a html/javascript web app. I used iOS and Android app to create an app that encapsulates the web app.

Is there a way to block access to the website link and only allow access to the website link only thru the native apps calling the link.

In short safari, IE, Chrome must not be able to access the link, but the iPhone & Android app should be able to access it.

Is there some way to tell that the app is accessing the site and not the phone or pc browsers.

I am sure there a number of ways to implement this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how is the web app implemented. Since native Web Views are pretty much the wrapper for the standard browser (Safari/Chrome), you will find it tough to filter it based on that.

What you can do, however, is to add an extra GET variable (for ex. `&ref=youruniquecodehere`) or a custom User-Agent, based on which you will be able to identify, whether your application authorized the request (with a proper access code) or if it's a generic request using browser.

However, both of these options can still be bypassed if researched, although it'd require slightly more time. Not sure whether a solution that would work in 100% of cases exists.

Hope that helps, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: 1. Yes it is exactly a wrapper. 2. I am inclined to that url solution. But I am afraid it then becomes a constant long term hardcoded solution than then is open to brute force to crack it. HTTPS may help encrypt this. But I am not sure if SSL will encrypt url parameters, may be POST variables to get parameters. Does SSL encrypt url GET parameters?

Comment: You're right, if you want to make picking the correct key significantly harder you'd have to send secure POST request (GET wouldn't work, I am afraid). You can also generate those keys inside the application (based on the username, for example) and validate them on a server.

Comment: I have not implemented registration yuet on it. But will be future course of action. Thanks,

Comment: I was hoping to see some other alternative solutions that would add some complicated solution harder to break into. For now will work with around this.